# adding a (href) hyperlink to html(convertTo-HTML) via powershell

Tags: powershell

I-m trying to add a `href` hyperlink to my HTML as below as I-m sending it as an email.

But it's not working for me.

Has anyone experienced this? How can I get this rolling?

```
$message.Body = $exportlist | Select-Object Sponsor,Activate,Category,FileName,@{name="Link"; expression={"<a href=""" + $web.Url + "/" + $_.Sponsor + "/Activate/" + $_.FileName + """>Link</a>"}} | ConvertTo-Html -Head $a
```

Comment: I never do that kind of stuff. but, don't you have to convert your email as an html one ? (Just an idea, dont be rude with me :p)

Comment: No worries Nico and you are not rude.I have this in my code:$message.IsBodyHTML = $true already.
Cheers.I just need some info how i can encode/decode the href links

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll be wrong again, but you are currently convert your href using an array (or custom table) with `@{}`, right ? What if you used a string variable before, that contains your `href` link ?

Comment: Thanks Nico but not sure what you are trying to say.
You mean build the url first before adding it to href?
But what i need is how to format it correctly to show up in the email.I need the <a href>sample</a> converted to sample(just the hyperlink)

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean, because I don't understand the use of a custom table here, and I thought this can be the conerting problem. If you use a string variable, with contains html(href), and your email is converted to HTML, then your string variable will show up a link, no ? Talking about theory, this should work.

Comment: Will have a look at it again and let you know.I think i get what you are saying just wanted to use "ConvertTo-Html" instead of building the html strings

Comment: For your reference this is what i can see in my html table:e.g
<a href="http://xxx/">Link</a>

Comment: Does this mean that you get what you want ?

Comment: No i haven't.just showing u what im getting instead of a proper hyperlink

Comment: Using  System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode did eventually did the trick. Thanks Guys